# Getting the proper document height with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Goodevening/night

A small yet annoying jquery problem. I would like to get the height of my document. To do that i use the following code:

```
$docHeight = $(document).height();
```

When i visit my page in a normal way (by clicking at a href at some other page) I get the correct height of my document. (about 4000px). But when i refresh i get my windowheight (1037px). Any way to avoid/fix this?

Grats,

W.

****Solution****

$(window).load(function({...}); does the trick. My images(so imageheight also) don't get loaded with document.ready, only the tags. window.load loads the entire page with heights etc, which gives me the right height of my doc.

Comment: You have this in document.ready?

Comment: Sounds like a race condition... (i.e. when reloading it uses cached data, so it renders faster.) Do you get the height in the `load` or `ready` event, so that the entire document is parsed?

Comment: Try putting your code within `$(window).load(function() { // ...})`

Comment: Yep it's in my document.ready

Comment: Seems like i'm only getting this error in Chrome. Firefox works fine.

Comment: Ah indeed the $(window).load fixes this problem. With my document.ready i only load my tags, not the heights of my images. Great, thx!

Comment: yeah, $(window).load will resolve this as it will calculate the height after all contents were loaded. There is another tricky way that I came up with is to use set a timeout which will delay retrieving the height of the document.

Comment: @WarreBuysse - Please add your solution as an answer and accept it. It will show others that this question has been resolved. Thanks!